# Creating new columns for a range of days and then filling with 1 or 0 based on that day falling between a start and end date of each row

Tags: sas

I'm finding this a bit difficult to explain what I mean, so I've added images of the tables of the input I have and the outputs I'm after for clarity.

Essentially, I've got a SAS dataset with (amongst other columns corresponding to different properties) two columns: start date and end date.

Say I have the following table:

[image]

If a day is within the start and end date (inclusive) for the item on a row then that item would be "in force" on that day. So UniqueID 6 is "in force" each day from 1 Jan 2018 to 3 Oct 2018.

I'm looking to summarise this data into several tables, one for each of the properties (Property1, Property2) which have a column for each day within a period (say 1 Oct 2018 to 5 Oct 2018) and then for each day they sum the total number of "in force" items attributed to each of the available property values.

So the output I want is:
[image: Property1 in force by day]

and:

[image: Property2 in force by day]

In excel I would break this down by adding a new column to the table for each day within the period I am interested in and then filling this in with a 1 or 0 based on whether that day fell within the start and end dates (inclusive). Then sumifs to sum for each property.

In excel I would go via making the following table:
[image: possible intermediate step?]

I'm trying to use SAS as it's quite a large dataset.

I am very new to SAS so I'm interested in whether there is a way to get these results using SAS?

Comment: Of course there's a way to do this in SAS but it would very much help if you posted your data as text, not images. Refer to the guidelines here on how to ask a question [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In situations like this I find it useful to fully expand the data first, then summarize as needed.  So I would start by creating a data set with one record per day:

```
data prelim (drop=uniqueid startdate enddate);
  set have;
  do day = startdate to enddate; output; end;
run;
```

Then you can use several techniques to summarize the data as desired. I would start by (using a simpler to understand version):

```
proc freq data=prelim noprint;
  tables property1 * day /out=property1_day (keep=property1 day count);
run;

proc sort data=property1_day;
  by property1;

proc transpose data=property1_day out=property1_summary (keep=property1 day:);
  by property1;
  id day;
  var count;
run;
```

This should get you most of the way - you might want to reset missings to zeroes (and I'm sure there are COMPLETETYPES or similar options to use), but I rarely use proc transpose.